# Phonegap Build: how to handle Back button in Android?

Tags: jquery, cordova

Can someone kindly explain me how to handle the Back button in Android with [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps)? I'm usign Jquery but NOT Jquery Mobile. I would simply like that the Back button reloads the page.

I tried the example founded at the [Phonegap's documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton) by building an APK with the 'full example' they provided and adding the line ' Alert("Hello!") ' inside the onBackKeyDown() function it did not display anything.

My webapp is a single HTML file which loads data from a MySQL dB with the .load function and appends the content to a DIV. As the app is a single file when the user taps the back button the app, of course, exits. To go back to the main page the web app must be reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have included the wrong cordova.js file? (They are platform specific)
This code should do the trick:

```js
function onBackButtonTapped() {
    document.location.reload(true);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButtonTapped, false);
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```